# Is there a single word which represents "siblings including myself"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that represents "my siblings and myself"? Equivalent to "the children of my parents", but more succinct?

Example sentence: "The dinner was paid for by my siblings and I".

I would like it to be clear but concise.

Comment: Aside: ... by my siblings and *me*. Variable naming in computer code is off topic, but `offspring` is more succinct than "the children of my parents".

Comment: "Us". There's not a single word for "me and my friends" or "me and my colleagues" or "me and my siblings" or anything similar; sometimes there is a word/short phrase that can be used, e.g. "friend group", "workforce", "family", but it depends on context.

Comment: @WeatherVane — *offspring* and *siblings* would function the same (both share the same parents). But does OP need the sense of “me and them”?

Comment: @TinfoilHat I get what you say, but 'siblings' is probably clearer than 'offspring', which might be yours or your parents'.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no single word, but I hope the OQ, Stuart F's Comment and jimm101's Answer would all be met by 'us/we siblings'.

Answer (score 0):

This does match a definition of **siblings**:

> one of two or more persons born of the same parents or, sometimes, having one parent in common; brother or sister

Yes, it is common to separate yourself when saying various forms of "me and my siblings", but term can refer to the group as a whole.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/sibling)

Comment: Whenever "siblings" is used with a possessive, it doesn't include the possessor. It only means the whole group when used as a general category, e.g. "The siblings split the inheritance."

Comment: @Barmar Is this true for the example sentence?

Comment: Yes. "my siblings" is in a possessive context, so it doesn't include yourself. But if someone else says "The dinner was paid for by the siblings", it means all the siblings.

Comment: Even more clear would be "The dinner was paid for by us siblings."